# Do world objects reset?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What I am trying to ask is: do objects placed somewhere by me simply reset?

Context: I use a cool "mod" (not really a mod just a savegame with some console tweaks) where I am a bandit (affiliated with all bandits) and so on and so forth. I have also added obscene bounties so I need to avoid most major cities. Thus I want to inhabit either bandit camps or abandoned houses, but I want to make them REALLY be mine, so I want to personalize  them. I know that anything I throw on the ground inside my own house won't reset, but what about a non-instanced shack (the ones you don't need a loading screen because it's not instanced) If I just place books, potions, armor, gold and other stuff will it eventually reset or disappear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a peek at [UESP's Housing page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim%3aHouses#Free_Shacks) and you can find a list of overworld 'houses' that have safe storage in them. However, I do not believe this would keep things placed on a table or a chair from resetting when that cell resets. (I even have problems getting things inside of a normal house to stay put!). At the very least I would expect you to find things in disarray when returning after a reset has happened.

Comment: I am very curious then ... How do they make stuff remain on the table (clutter like pots and pans). I'm sure the Construction Kit will make things a whole lot easier but I can't imagine that you need to flag items so they don't reset with the rest of the cell or when the cell resets the items get erased and other items placed in their default position ... oh nvm that makes perfect sense :(

Comment: Yeah, things generally seem to be 'reverted' to their originally designed state once a reset goes through.

Comment: OH one more thing. I don't want to buy a house because I can't set foot in any city ... and I don't want to be able. I'm an outlaw :D and I want to RP as one hence I have none of the main quests (disabled the civil war and dragonborne questline)

Comment: Updated the link to take you directly to the free shacks section that contain safe storage (Containers that do not reset)

Answer (score 0):

I once dropped some stuff on the ground just inside the gate of Whiterun. I went out to do a quest and when I came back my stuff was still there, so my final answer would be maybe.

Comment: Same, there are parts in the world where I have just DUMPED crap because I was over burdened. Then when I've gone back - Whiterun: city street, it was still there.  This was the same case at the college of winter hold, front door.

Comment: I am affraid that it should still respawn once the cell respawns (once a month) but I don't have the patience to test this out I'm afraid.